TYPO3 Solr: disable no_cache param in links in result list?
TYPO3 10, Solr 11.2 and PHP 7.4.
also observed in: TYPO3 11, Solr 11.5 and PHP 8.1
The links in the result list container are appended by a &no_cache=1 variable. How to disable this?
In the documentation I cannot find anything about this feature. I actively did not configure it like this. It seems to be a default.
It is possible to de-activate the no_cache param with TYPO3_CONF_VARS[FE][disableNoCacheParameter] = true Then it is still visible in the URL, but hopefully without effect. The question is, how to make this query variable disappear.

The no_cache param is set in the AddSearchWordListViewHelper. The call in the template Document.html must be appended with AddNoCache: 0.
<a href="{s:uri.result.addSearchWordList(url:document.url, searchWords:resultSet.usedQuery.query, addNoCache: 0)}">

